# How to use Touches Began properly with CGPoint

Tags: objective-c, touchesbegan

The goal here is that when i tap the screen to the right or left of the UIImageview the Int side movement changes to create a left or right movement.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

 CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];


if (image.center.x > touchLocation) {
    sidemovement = -2;

}
if (if (image.center.x < touchLocation) {
    sidemovement = 2;)



[self jump];



}
```

The problem is that I want the CGpoint touch location to be compared to the image.center.x location and with that determine if the image should move left or right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Objective-C, but maybe some of this might help you, and if I misunderstood your question, my apologies.

Are you trying to move an image left and right?  If so, you have to create a CCPhysicsNode first, then make sure the image is a CCNode, and then add the image to the CCPhysicsNode.

You would do that like this

```
CCPhysicsNode *physicsNode;
CCNode *image;
```

then call this in your init or whatever method you want to put the image in the physics node

```
[physicsNode addChild:image];
```

Now, you can call this to move your image left or right (P.S., i'm not sure if your image.center.x > touchLocationn is valid or not.  But assuming it is....)

```
if (image.center.x > touchLocation) {
 [image.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(-2.f, 0.f)];

}
if (image.center.x < touchLocation) {
 [image.physicsBody applyImpulse:ccp(2.f, 0.f)];
 [self jump];

}
```

You also had extra if's and parentheses in your example code.
Hope this addressed your question...if not, well...it was fun writing it!  And if anyone sees error in what I typed, let me know - I'm still learning.